# iOS - Detect shake strength

Tags: iphone, ios, shake

i need to detect the strength of the shake. I have to move some objects on the screen basing to shake strength. Is it possible with iOS SDK API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally possible. Check out Core Motion and UIAccelerometer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html